# Responsive navigation menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a responsive navigation menu for my website. However, it should also stick to the top when you scroll further down the page. This works fine on the normal 'desktop-size' menu, but when I expand the list items in the responsive navigation menu, the whole menu re-positions itself back to the top.

```
let navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
let offset = navbar.offsetTop;

// Makes the menu sticky
function stick() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= offset) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}

// Makes the menu responsive
function collapse() {
    if (navbar.className === "responsive") {
        navbar.classList.remove("responsive");
    } else {
        navbar.classList.add("responsive")
    }
}
```

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MihkelPajunen/t37g6hsc/

**Question:** Is there a way to make the responsive navigation menu sticky, so that the menu is accessible at the top of the page, even when you scroll further down the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following rule:

```
nav.responsive {
    position: relative;
}
```

As this is overriding the `position: fixed` rule.

Also, change the collapse function like so:

```
if (navbar.className.indexOf("responsive") >=0 ) {
```

As the class name will actually be something like "responsive sticky"

[Here's a fork of that fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwawwcpu/)

Answer (score 0):

Try To use this one instead of yours

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```